# How does subtracting 0x1 - 0x80000000 cause an overflow?

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

```
  MOV   R0, #0x80000000 
  MOV   R1, #0x1 
  SUBS  R2, R1, R0
```

Upon Running this code, Flag N and Z are set. Now, I know N flag is set if the operation results in a negative result and Z flag is set when there is an overflow.

The thing I don't understand is that how does `0x1 - 0x80000000`  causes overflow. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Note that in two's complement `0x80000000` is its own negative. The negative is obtained by "flip the bits and add one". Doing this for `0x80000000` gives `0x7FFFFFFF + 1 = 0x80000000`. But adding `0x7FFFFFFF + 1` produces an overflow. This could be related to your observation

Comment: The `Z` flag is set when there is an overflow?  Also, our interpretation of overflow is dependent upon whether this is signed or unsigned arithmetic, and, you haven't specified.

Comment: @CherryDT: In general, signed-overflow flag results are not the same from `x - y` vs. `x + (-y)` if you consider `-(-128)` as overflowing back to `-128`.  For example, in 8-bit, `-100 - (-128) => 28` does *not* overflow, even though `-100 + (-128) => 28` with 8-bit wrapping would.  But the OP's case is true overflow, like `1 - (-128) => -127` because the true result would be `129`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider extending the two numbers to 36 bits. 1 is still 1, of course. 80000000 becomes f80000000. 1 - f80000000 = 080000001, a positive number. Since 080000001 doesn't fit in 32 bits as a positive number, there is overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
    1
 1000 
+1110
======

10001
 1000 
+1110
======
 0111
```

carry in and carry out of msbit are not the same...signed overflow.